# Como extrair valores da estatística calculada pela função linhom (L-function for inhomogeneous spatial point processes)?

Tags: r

Tenho de analisar o padrão espacial de algumas distribuições de cactos no campo, e uma vez que são heterogêneos, não posso usar a função K de Ripley (e correspondente função L) para padrões estacionários. Com o pacote spatstat, calculei e plotei a função L "in-homogênea". Mas gostaria de obter os valores calculados, para poder especificar em que valores exatamente a curva apresenta mudança de padrão.

Aqui vai um exemplo:

```
m22.X<-c(16809,4705,19772,5294,107,623,17361,19397,2827,3875,17326,12150,9827,11853,8888,10973,2015,3528,3751,3406,3425,276,1693,44,9794,664,701,762,3601,5577,15122,4757,6293,5077,4801,972,5133,6077,4754, 18036,12805,18731,12312,3414,3405,3369,17476,16794,19343,17703, 11834,11913,11931)
m22.Y<-c(15691,5662,15168,2389,16703,15305,15372,19822,8108,17493,10783, 9227,281,8153,11943,14446,18802,15551,17505,15598,18134,15904, 18151,16408,179,17807,17801,17007,19342,16003,124,3041,5605,3107, 3072,3309,5905,5904,7500,12377,8312,14056,8315,15574,15601,18867, 15298,16224,17420,15556,19724,19778,19577)

# cria objeto espacial para spatstat:
loc.m22<-ppp(m22.X,m22.Y,c(0,20000), c(0,20000))

# calcula Linhom(...)
linm22<-Linhom(loc.m22, correction="best")
plot(linm22,lwd=2)

#calcula intervalo de confiança de L:
bootlm22<-lohboot(loc.m22,fun="Linhom",nsim=1000,correction="best",confidence=0.95,type=7)
plot(bootlm22,lwd=2)
```

Então, no gráfico, vocês podem ver que a área sombreada do intervalo de confiança intercepta a linha pontilhada (que marca valores de L para uma distribuição de Poisson) mais ou menos quando r=1.300, mas que a linha cheia só intercepta mais ou menos em r=2.500. Mas quais são os valores exatos? Eu tentei o seguinte:

```
theo.values<-bootlm22$theo
iso.values<-bootlm22$iso
r.values<-bootlm22$r
matriz<-cbind(r.values,theo.values,iso.values)
matriz
#no local da interceptação, o valor de iso(L calculado) == valor de r 
intercept<-matriz[(matriz[,1]==matriz[,3]),]
```

mas não deu certo. Alguém tem alguma ideia? já vasculhei os atributos da função linhom, mas não encontrei um campo que correspondesse ao que eu quero.

Obrigada, Leila

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como você já deve ter visto, pode recuperar os valores do intervalo de confiança mínimo usando `bootlm22$lo`, o valor estimado com `bootlm22$iso`, o valor teórico com `bootlm22$theo` e o valor de `r` com `bootlm22$r`. Associando estes vetores, podemos encontrar os pontos que eles se encontram.

```
lo <- bootlm22$lo
iso <- bootlm22$iso
theo <- bootlm22$theo
r <- bootlm22$r
```

O cuidado que deve ser tomado é que os valores entre os três valores do eixo `y` não são idênticos para o mesmo `r`, mesmo onde ocorre a interseção. Para encontrar os valores, podemos procurar as menores diferenças entre um vetor e outro. Primeiro, para o intervalo de confiança inferior:

```
difflothe <- abs(lo - theo)
```

Os menores valores deste vetor são aqueles valores de `lo` que estão mais próximos de `theo`:

```
head(sort(difflothe))
#[1] 0.000000 1.000166 2.015760 2.883821 4.266349 5.499276
```

Obviamente ao fazer o sort perdemos a relação com `r`, mas podemos procurar os três menores valores em `difflothe` sem perder a ordem:

```
which(difflothe %in% sort(difflothe)[1:10])
#[1]   1   2   5   7   8  11 138 139 140 141
```

Vemos que existem valores no início da curva que não são o que estamos procurando. Se diminuirmos a quantidade de valores do `sort`:

```
which(difflothe %in% sort(difflothe)[1:3])
#[1]   1  11 140
```

Assim, podemos ignorar 1 e 11, e o valor procurado é o elemento 140, ou seja:

```
v1 <- r[140]
```

Utilizando o mesmo raciocínio para o valor `iso`:

```
diffisothe <- abs(iso - theo)
which(diffisothe %in% sort(diffisothe)[1:3])
#[1]   1 269 270
v2 <- r[269]
```

Podemos conferir que estes são os resultados que queremos colocando-os no gráfico:

```
abline(v = v1)
abline(v = v2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os valores de `r` salvos em `v1` e `v2` são:

```
> v1
[1] 1357.422
> v2
[1] 2617.188
```

É difícil automatizar essa abordagem já que há uma região no início que deve ser ignorada, mas se houver um `r` mínimo isso poderia ser corrigido.

Comment: Uau, @Molx! Obrigada! Já facilitou muito! Funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: @Leila, se a resposta do Molx te atendeu, você pode aceitá-la clicando no botão de "ok" à esquerda!

Comment: Obrigada, @CarlosCinelli